# Encoders.bean doesn't work anymore on a Java POJO, with Spark 3.4.0

Tags: java, apache-spark

This method that worked well from Spark `3.2.x` to Spark `3.3.x`,

```java
public Dataset<Commune> obtenirCommunes(SparkSession session, int anneeCOG) throws TechniqueException {
   Dataset<Row> communes = rowCommunes(session, anneeCOG);

   return communes
      .select(communes.col("typeCommune"), communes.col("codeCommune"), communes.col("codeRegion"), communes.col("codeDepartement"),
          communes.col("arrondissement"), communes.col("typeNomEtCharniere"), communes.col("nomMajuscules"), communes.col("nomCommune"), 
          communes.col("codeCanton"), communes.col("codeCommuneParente"), communes.col("sirenCommune"), communes.col("populationTotale").alias("population"),
          communes.col("strateCommune"), communes.col("codeEPCI"), communes.col("surface"), communes.col("longitude"), communes.col("latitude"),
          communes.col("nomDepartement"), communes.col("nomEPCI"))
      .as(Encoders.bean(Commune.class))
      .cache();
   }
```

is now failing with Spark `3.4.0`, through this test:

```java
/**
 * Charger le Code Officiel Géographique entier.
 * @throws CommuneInexistanteException si la commune recherchée n'existe pas.
 * @throws TechniqueException si un incident survient.
 */
@Test
@DisplayName("Lecture du code officiel géographique")
void cog() throws TechniqueException, CommuneInexistanteException {
   for(int cog = COG_START; cog <= COG_END; cog ++) {
      if (this.toutesAnnees == false && cog != COG_END) {
         continue;
      }
         
      CodeOfficielGeographique maillage = this.cogDataset.obtenirCodeOfficielGeographique(this.session, cog, true);
      LOGGER.info("Code Officiel Géographique : {} communes, {} intercommunalités.", maillage.getCommunes().size(), maillage.getIntercommunalites().size());
         
      Intercommunalite intercommunalite = maillage.getIntercommunalites().values().iterator().next();
      LOGGER.info("La première intercommunalité : {}", intercommunalite);
         
      Commune cambremer = maillage.getCommune("14126");
      assertNotNull(cambremer, MessageFormat.format("Cambremer aurait dû être trouvé dans le COG {0}.", cog));
      LOGGER.info(cambremer.toString());
   }
}
```

The failure comes with a not very clear log (it's the line `CodeOfficielGeographique maillage = this.cogDataset.obtenirCodeOfficielGeographique(this.session, cog, true)` that calls `CogDataset:obtenirCommunes` who fails):

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:627)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.$anonfun$deserializerFor$8(ScalaReflection.scala:359)
    at scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq.map(ArraySeq.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq.map(ArraySeq.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.deserializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.deserializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.javaBean(ExpressionEncoder.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.bean(Encoders.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.bean(Encoders.scala)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.cog.CogDataset.obtenirCommunes(CogDataset.java:220)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.cog.CogDataset.obtenirCodeOfficielGeographique(CogDataset.java:186)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.cog.CommuneObjectsMetiersIT.cog(CommuneObjectsMetiersIT.java:92)
```

And the `Commune` object that `Encoders.bean` targets, is this one:

```java
package fr.ecoemploi.metier.territoire;

import static fr.ecoemploi.metier.territoire.PrefixageNomCommune.*;

import java.io.Serial;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import javax.validation.constraints.*;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;

import fr.fondation.utilitaires.autocontrole.*;
import fr.fondation.utilitaires.localisation.*;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.*;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.*;

/**
 * Une commune.
 * @author Marc LE BIHAN.
 */
@Schema(description = "Une commune du Code Officiel Géographique")
public class Commune extends ObjetMetierSpark {
   /** Serial ID */
   @Serial
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 4381577514414536917L;

   /** Collator utilisé pour comparer les noms de communes, sans accents. */
   private static final Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
   
   static {
      collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
   }

   /** Code de la commune. */
   @NotNull @Size(min = 5, max = 5) @Schema(description = "Code de la commune", example = "29019")
   private String codeCommune;
   
   /** Code ddépartement. */
   @NotNull @Size(min=2, max=3) @Schema(description = "Code du département", example = "972")
   private String codeDepartement;
   
   /** Nom du département. */
   @NotNull @Schema(description = "Nom du département", example = "Finistère")
   private String nomDepartement;

   /** Code de la commune parente (pour arrondissements, communes associées ou déléguées). */
   @Size(min = 9, max = 9) @Schema(description = "Code de la commune parente", example = "75056", nullable = true)
   private String codeCommuneParente;

   /** Code INSEE de la région auquel appartient ce département. */
   @NotNull @Size(min = 2, max = 2) @Schema(description = "Code de la région", example = "84")
   private String codeRegion;
   
   /** Code Canton de la commune. */
   @Schema(description = "Code du canton", nullable = true)
   private String codeCanton;

   /** Nom de la ville. */
   @NotNull @Schema(description = "Nom de la commune", example = "Brest")
   private String nomCommune;

   /** Nom en majuscule. */
   @NotNull @Schema(description = "Nom de la commune en majuscules", example = "BREST")
   private String nomMajuscules;

   /** Type et nom charnière. */
   @NotNull @Size(min=1, max=1)
   @Schema(description = "Type de nom et charnière: <ul>"
         + "<li>0  Pas d'article et le nom commence par une consonne sauf H muet  charnière = DE</li>"
         + "<li>1  Pas d'article et le nom commence par une voyelle ou un H muet  charnière = D'</li>"
         + "<li>2  Article = LE   charnière = DU</li>"
         + "<li>3  Article = LA   charnière = DE LA</li>"
         + "<li>4  Article = LES  charnière = DES</li>"
         + "<li>5  Article = L'   charnière = DE L'</li>"
         + "<li>6  Article = AUX  charnière = DES</li>"
         + "<li>7  Article = LAS  charnière = DE LAS</li>"
         + "<li>8  Article = LOS  charnière = DE LOS</li>"
         + "</ul>")
   private String typeNomEtCharniere;

   /** SIREN de la commune (permet de la lier à son intercommunalité). */
   @NotNull @Size(min=9, max=9) @Schema(description = "Numéro SIREN de la commune", example = "212900195")
   private String sirenCommune;

   /** Liste des groupements dont cette commune est le siège. */
   @NotNull 
   @Schema(description = "Liste des groupements (EPCI, ultérieurement : syndicats) dont cette commune est le siège. "
         + "Cette liste est vide si la commune n'est siège d'aucun syndicat ou intercommunalité.", example = "[242900314]")
   private Set<String> siegeGroupements = new HashSet<>();
   
   /** Liste des intercommunalités dont cette commune est membre. */
   @NotNull @Schema(description = "Liste des groupepements (EPCI, ultérieurement : syndicats) dont cette commune est membre.", example = "[242900314]")
   private Set<String> membreGroupements = new HashSet<>();
   
   /** Intercommunalité à fiscalité propre à laquelle cette commune appartient (qu'elle en soit siège ou membre). */
   @NotNull @Size(min=9, max=9) @Schema(description = "Numéro SIREN de l'intercommunalité dont cette commune est siège ou membre.", example = "242900314")
   private String epciFiscalitePropre;
   
   /** Nom de de l'intercommunalité à laquelle la commune appartient. */
   @NotNull @Schema(description = "Nom de l'intercommunalité à laquelle la commune appartient", example = "Brest Métropole")
   private String nomEPCI;
   
   /** Arrondissement de la commune. */
   @Schema(description = "Code de l'arrondissement de la commune.", nullable = true)
   private String arrondissement;
   
   /** Population de la commune. */
   @NotNull @Schema(description = "Population totale de la commune.")
   private Integer population;
   
   /** Type de la commune. */
   @NotNull
   @Schema(description = "Type de la commune : <ul>" +
      "<li>COM   Commune</li>" + 
      "<li>COMA  Commune associée</li>" + 
      "<li>COMD  Commune déléguée</li>" + 
      "<li>ARM   Arrondissement municipal</li>"
      + "</ul>", example = "COM")
   private String typeCommune;
   
   /** Strate communale. */
   @NotNull
   @Schema(description = "Strate communale : <ul>" +
         "<li>1 : Moins de 100 habitants</li>" + 
         "<li>2 : De 100 à moins de 200 habitants</li>" + 
         "<li>3 : De 200 à moins de 500 habitants</li>" + 
         "<li>4 : De 500 à moins de 2 000 habitants</li>" + 
         "<li>5 : De 2 000 à moins de 3 500 habitants</li>" + 
         "<li>6 : De 3 500 à moins de 5 000 habitants</li>" + 
         "<li>7 : De 5 000 à moins de 10 000 habitants</li>" + 
         "<li>8 : de 10 000 à moins de 20 000 habitants</li>" + 
         "<li>9 : de 20 000 à moins de 50 000 habitants</li>" + 
         "<li>10 : de 50 000 à moins de 100 000 habitants</li>" + 
         "<li>11 : 100 000 habitants et plus</li>" + 
         "</ul>", example = "1")
   private Integer strateCommune;
   
   /** Surface de la commune en hectares. */
   @Schema(description = "Surface de la commune, en hectares. N'est pas alimenté pour les arrondissements.", example = "1520.25", nullable = true)
   private Double surface;
   
   /** Longitude du centroïde de la commune. */
   @Schema(description = "Longitude du centroïde de la commune. N'est pas alimenté pour les arrondissements.", example = "-4.2908", nullable = true)
   private Double longitude;
   
   /** Latitude du centroïde de la commune. */
   @Schema(description = "Latitude du centroïde de la commune. N'est pas alimenté pour les arrondissements.", example = "48.2327", nullable = true)
   private Double latitude;

   /**
    * Construire une commune.
    */
   public Commune() {
   }
   
   /**
    * Ajouter une intercommunalité dont cette commune est membre.
    * @param sirenIntercommunalite SIREN de l'intercommunalité.
    */
   public void ajouterMembreGroupement(String sirenIntercommunalite) {
      this.membreGroupements.add(sirenIntercommunalite);
   }
   
   /**
    * Ajouter une intercommunalité dont cette commune est le siège.
    * @param sirenIntercommunalite SIREN de l'intercommunalité.
    */
   public void ajouterSiegeGroupement(String sirenIntercommunalite) {
      this.siegeGroupements.add(sirenIntercommunalite);
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code Canton de la commune. 
    * @return Code canton de la commune.
    */
   public String getCodeCanton() {
      return this.codeCanton;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le code canton de la commune.
    * @param codeCanton Code canton de la commune.
    */
   public void setCodeCanton(String codeCanton) {
      this.codeCanton = codeCanton;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code de la commune.
    * @return Code de la commune.
    */
   public String getCodeCommune() {
      return this.codeCommune;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code de la commune.
    * @return Code de la commune.
    */
   public CodeCommune astCodeCommune() {
      return new CodeCommune(this.codeCommune);
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code commune parente (pour arrondissements, communes associées ou déléguées).
    * @return Code commune parente.
    */
   public CodeCommune astCodeCommuneParente() {
      return new CodeCommune(this.codeCommuneParente);
   }
   
   /**
    * Renvoyer le code commune parente (pour arrondissements, communes associées ou déléguées).
    * @return Code commune parente.
    */
   public String getCodeCommuneParente() {
      return this.codeCommuneParente;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code département.
    * @return Code département.
    */
   public CodeDepartement asCodeDepartement() {
      return new CodeDepartement(this.codeDepartement);
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code département.
    * @return Code département.
    */
   public String getCodeDepartement() {
      return this.codeDepartement;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code région.
    * @return Code région.
    */
   public CodeRegion asCodeRegion() {
      return new CodeRegion(this.codeRegion);
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code région.
    * @return Code région.
    */
   public String getCodeRegion() {
      return this.codeRegion;
   }
   
   /**
    * Renvoyer l'intercommunalité à fiscalité propre à laquelle cette commune appartient, qu'elle en soit siège ou membre.
    * @return Intercommunalité.
    */
   public SIREN asEpciFiscalitePropre() {
      return new SIREN(this.epciFiscalitePropre);
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer l'intercommunalité à fiscalité propre à laquelle cette commune appartient, qu'elle en soit siège ou membre.
    * @return Intercommunalité.
    */
   @Hidden
   public String getCodeEPCI() {
      return this.epciFiscalitePropre;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer l'intercommunalité à fiscalité propre à laquelle cette commune appartient, qu'elle en soit siège ou membre.
    * @param epci Intercommunalité.
    */
   @Hidden
   public void setCodeEPCI(String epci) {
      this.epciFiscalitePropre = epci;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer les groupements dont cette commune est membre.
    * @return Groupements.
    */
   public Set<String> membreGroupements() {
      return this.membreGroupements;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer la liste des groupements dont cette commune est le siège.
    * @return liste des groupements.
    */
   public Set<String> siegeGroupements() {
      return this.siegeGroupements;
   }
   
   /**
    * Renvoyer l'arrondissement.
    * @return Arrondissement.
    */
   public String getArrondissement() {
      return this.arrondissement;
   }
   
   /**
    * Déterminer si ce code commune désigne une collectivité d'outre-mer :<br>
    * Attention, il s'agit des départements 975, 977, 978 et 98, et pas les départements d'outremer 971, 972, 973, 974 et 976.
    * @return true si c'est le cas.
    */
   @Hidden
   public boolean isCollectiviteOutremer() {
      return this.codeCommune != null &&
         (this.codeCommune.startsWith("975") || this.codeCommune.startsWith("977") || this.codeCommune.startsWith("978") || this.codeCommune.startsWith("98"));
   }

   /**
    * Fixer l'arrondissement.
    * @param arrondissement Arrondissement.
    */
   public void setArrondissement(String arrondissement) {
      this.arrondissement = arrondissement;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le nom de la commune.
    * @return Nom de la commune.
    */
   public String getNomCommune() {
      return this.nomCommune;
   }
   
   /**
    * Déterminer si notre commune a le même nom que celle en paramètre.
    * @param nomCandidat Nom de commune : il peut contenir une charnière.
    * @return true si c'est le cas.
    */
   public boolean hasMemeNom(String nomCandidat) {
      // Si le nom soumis vaut null, répondre non.
      if (nomCandidat == null) {
         return false;
      }

      // Faire une comparaison directe de nom de commune tout d'abord, car l'emploi du collator est très coûteux.
      if (nomCandidat.equalsIgnoreCase(this.nomCommune)) {
         return true;
      }
      
      // Puis, rechercher avec les différentes charnières.
      if (nomCandidat.equalsIgnoreCase(nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.AUCUN))) {
         return true;
      }
      
      if (nomCandidat.equalsIgnoreCase(nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.A))) {
         return true;
      }
      
      if (nomCandidat.equalsIgnoreCase(nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.POUR))) {
         return true;
      }
      
      // En cas d'échec, reprendre ces tests, mais avec le collator, plus lent, mais qui passera outre les caractères accentués.
      if (collator.equals(nomCandidat, this.nomCommune)) {
         return true;
      }
      
      if (collator.equals(nomCandidat, nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.AUCUN))) {
         return true;
      }
      
      if (collator.equals(nomCandidat, nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.A))) {
         return true;
      }

      if (collator.equals(nomCandidat, nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.POUR))) {
         return true;
      }

      // Alternative aux tests précédents
      List<Predicate<String>> memeNoms = new ArrayList<>();
      memeNoms.add(nom -> nom.equalsIgnoreCase(nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.AUCUN)));
      memeNoms.add(nom -> nom.equalsIgnoreCase(nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.A)));
      memeNoms.add(nom -> nom.equalsIgnoreCase(nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.POUR)));
      memeNoms.add(nom -> collator.equals(nom, this.nomCommune));
      memeNoms.add(nom -> collator.equals(nom, nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.AUCUN)));
      memeNoms.add(nom -> collator.equals(nom, nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.A)));
      memeNoms.add(nom -> collator.equals(nom, nomAvecType(false, PrefixageNomCommune.POUR)));

      return memeNoms.stream().anyMatch(memeNom -> memeNom.test(nomCandidat));
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le nom de la commune avec sa charnière accolée : Ville D'Ermenouville, Ville de Villenoy
    * @param majuscules true S'il faut que la ville et sa charnière soient en majuscules.
    * @return Nom de la commune avec sa charnière.
    */
   public String nomAvecCharniere(boolean majuscules) {
      String articleCommune = switch(asArticleEtCharniere()) {
         case AUCUN_D_APOSTROPHE -> "d'";
         case AUX_DES, LES_DES -> "des ";
         case LAS_DE_LAS -> "de las ";
         case LA_DE_LA -> "de la ";
         case LE_DU -> "du ";
         case LOS_DE_LOS -> "de los ";
         case L_APOSTROPHE_DE_L_APOSTROPHE -> "l'";
         default -> // inclut le cas : AUCUN_CONSONNE_DE
            "de ";
      };

      String texte = articleCommune + (majuscules ? this.nomMajuscules : this.nomCommune);
      return majuscules ? texte.toUpperCase(Locale.FRENCH) : texte;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le nom de la commune avec son type accolé : Bienvenue à Ermenouville, Bienvenue aux Ullis.
    * @param majuscules true S'il faut que la ville et sa charnière soient en majuscules.
    * @param prefixage Indique s'il faut replacer type vide par 'à', 'pour' : "Bienvenue à St-Etienne", "pour les Ullis".
    * @return Nom de la commune avec sa charnière.
    */
   public String nomAvecType(boolean majuscules, PrefixageNomCommune prefixage) {
      String articleCommune = "";
      String prefixe = "";

      final String PREFIXE_POUR = "pour ";

      switch(asArticleEtCharniere()) {
         case AUCUN_CONSONNE_DE -> {
            if (prefixage.equals(A))
               articleCommune = "à ";

            if (prefixage.equals(POUR))
               prefixe = PREFIXE_POUR;
         }

         case AUCUN_D_APOSTROPHE -> {
            if (prefixage.equals(A))
               prefixe = "à ";

            if (prefixage.equals(POUR))
               prefixe = PREFIXE_POUR;
         }

         case AUX_DES -> articleCommune = "aux ";

         case LAS_DE_LAS -> {
            articleCommune = "las ";

            if (prefixage.equals(POUR))
               prefixe = PREFIXE_POUR;
         }

         case LA_DE_LA -> {
            articleCommune = "la ";

            if (prefixage.equals(POUR))
               prefixe = PREFIXE_POUR;
         }

         case LES_DES -> {
            articleCommune = "les ";

            if (prefixage.equals(POUR))
               prefixe = PREFIXE_POUR;
         }

         case LE_DU -> {
            articleCommune = "le ";

            if (prefixage.equals(POUR))
               prefixe = PREFIXE_POUR;
         }

         case LOS_DE_LOS -> {
            articleCommune = "los ";

            if (prefixage.equals(POUR))
               prefixe = PREFIXE_POUR;
         }

         case L_APOSTROPHE_DE_L_APOSTROPHE -> {
            articleCommune = "l'";

            if (prefixage.equals(POUR))
               prefixe = PREFIXE_POUR;
         }

         default -> {
            if (prefixage.equals(A))
               prefixe = "à ";
         }
      }

      String texte = prefixe + articleCommune + (majuscules ? this.nomMajuscules : this.nomCommune);
      return majuscules ? texte.toUpperCase(Locale.FRENCH) : texte;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le nom de la commune en majuscules.
    * @return Nom de la commune.
    */
   public String getNomMajuscules() {
      return this.nomMajuscules;
   }
   
   /**
    * Obtenir la population de la commune une année particulière.
    * @return population de la commune.
    */
   public Integer getPopulation() {
      return this.population;
   }

   /**
    * Convertit un type de nom INSEE en enum charnière INSEE.
    * @return Enumération.
    */
   public ArticleEtCharniereINSEE asArticleEtCharniere() {
      for(ArticleEtCharniereINSEE candidat : ArticleEtCharniereINSEE.values()) {
         if (candidat.getCode().equals(this.typeNomEtCharniere))
            return candidat;
      }

      return null;
   }
   
   /**
    * Renvoyer l'article et la charnière.
    * @return Article et charnière.
    */
   public String getTypeNomEtCharniere() {
      return this.typeNomEtCharniere;
   }
   
   /**
    * Déterminer si la commune a un numéro de SIREN alimenté
    * (elle en a forcément un, mais parfois l'objet métier ne le porte pas encore).
    * @return true, si c'est le cas.
    */
   public boolean hasSIREN() {
      return this.sirenCommune != null && StringUtils.isBlank(this.sirenCommune) == false;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le code de la commune.
    * @param code Code de la commune.
    */
   public void setCodeCommune(String code) {
      this.codeCommune = code;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le code de la commune parente (pour arrondissements, communes associées ou déléguées).
    * @param code Code de la commune parente (pour arrondissements, communes associées ou déléguées).
    */
   public void setCodeCommuneParente(String code) {
      this.codeCommuneParente = code;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le code département.
    * @param code Code département.
    */
   public void setCodeDepartement(String code) {
      this.codeDepartement = code;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le code région.
    * @param code Code région.
    */
   public void setCodeRegion(String code) {
      this.codeRegion = code;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer les groupements dont cette commune est membre.
    * @param groupements Groupements.
    */
   public void membreGroupements(Set<String> groupements) {
      this.membreGroupements = groupements;
   }
   
   /**
    * Fixer les groupements dont cette commune est le siège.
    * @param siegeIntercommunalites Intercommunalités.
    */
   public void siegeGroupements(Set<String> siegeIntercommunalites) {
      this.siegeGroupements = siegeIntercommunalites;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer la latitude de la commune.
    * @return Latitude de la commune.
    */
   public Double getLatitude() {
      return this.latitude;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer la latitude de la commune.
    * @param latitude Latitude de la commune.
    */
   public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
      this.latitude = latitude;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer la longitude de la commune.
    * @return Longitude de la commune.
    */
   public Double getLongitude() {
      return this.longitude;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer la longitude de la commune.
    * @param longitude Longitude de la commune. 
    */
   public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
      this.longitude = longitude;
   }
   
   /**
    * Renvoyer le nom du département.
    * @return Nom du département.
    */
   public String getNomDepartement() {
      return this.nomDepartement;
   }
   
   /**
    * Fixer le nom du département.
    * @param nomDepartement Nom du département.
    */
   public void setNomDepartement(String nomDepartement) {
      this.nomDepartement = nomDepartement;
   }
   
   /**
    * Renvoyer le nom de l'EPCI dont la commune est membre ou siège.
    * @return Nom de l'EPCI.
    */
   public String getNomEPCI() {
      return this.nomEPCI;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le nom de l'EPCI dont la commune est membre ou siège.
    * @param nomEPCI Nom de l'EPCI.
    */
   public void setNomEPCI(String nomEPCI) {
      this.nomEPCI = nomEPCI;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le nom de la ville.
    * @param nomVille Nom de la ville.
    */
   public void setNomCommune(String nomVille) {
      this.nomCommune = nomVille;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le nom de la commune en majuscules.
    * @param nomVille Nom de la commune.
    */
   public void setNomMajuscules(String nomVille) {
      this.nomMajuscules = nomVille;
   }
   
   /**
    * Fixer la population de la commune une année donnée.
    * @param population Population.
    */
   public void setPopulation(Integer population) {
      this.population = population;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le SIREN de la commune.
    * @return SIREN.
    */
   public SIRENCommune asSiren() {
      return new SIRENCommune(this.sirenCommune);
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le SIREN de la commune.
    * @return SIREN.
    */
   public String getSirenCommune() {
      return this.sirenCommune;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le code SIREN de la commune.
    * @param sirenCommune Siren.
    */
   public void setSirenCommune(String sirenCommune) {
      this.sirenCommune = sirenCommune;
   }
   
   /**
    * Renvoyer la strate communale.
    * @return Strate :<br>
    * 1 : Moins de 100 habitants<br> 
    * 2 : De 100 à moins de 200 habitants<br>
    * 3 : De 200 à moins de 500 habitants<br>
    * 4 : De 500 à moins de 2 000 habitants<br>
    * 5 : De 2 000 à moins de 3 500 habitants<br>
    * 6 : De 3 500 à moins de 5 000 habitants<br>
    * 7 : De 5 000 à moins de 10 000 habitants<br>
    * 8 : de 10 000 à moins de 20 000 habitants<br>
    * 9 : de 20 000 à moins de 50 000 habitants<br>
    * 10 : de 50 000 à moins de 100 000 habitants<br>
    * 11 : 100 000 habitants et plus
    */
   public Integer getStrateCommune() {
      return this.strateCommune;
   }
   
   /**
    * Fixer la strate communale.
    * @param strate Strate communele.
    */
   public void setStrateCommune(Integer strate) {
      this.strateCommune = strate;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer la surface de la commune, en hectares.
    * @return Surface en hectares.
    */
   public Double getSurface() {
      return this.surface;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer la surface de la communes, en hectares.
    * @param surface Surface en hectares.
    */
   public void setSurface(Double surface) {
      this.surface = surface;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le type nom et charnière.
    * @param type Type nom et charnière.
    */
   public void setTypeNomEtCharniere(String type) {
      this.typeNomEtCharniere = type;
   }
   
   /**
    * Renvoyer le type de commune. 
    * @return Type de commune.
    */
   public String getTypeCommune() {
      return this.typeCommune;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le type de commune.
    * @param typeDeCommune Type de commune.
    */
   public void setTypeCommune(String typeDeCommune) {
      this.typeCommune = typeDeCommune;
   }

   /**
    * @see fr.fondation.objets.ObjetMetierIdentifiable#toString()
    */
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return BabelTower.format(Commune.class, "toString", this.nomCommune, this.nomMajuscules, this.codeDepartement, this.codeRegion,
         this.codeCommuneParente, this.typeNomEtCharniere, this.codeCommune, this.sirenCommune, this.siegeGroupements, 
         this.membreGroupements, this.epciFiscalitePropre, this.arrondissement, this.codeCanton, this.population, this.strateCommune,
         this.surface, this.longitude, this.latitude, this.nomDepartement, this.nomEPCI);
   }
}
```

My hypothethis is that `Encoders.bean` change its way of working in `3.4.0`, or its prerequisites, but I have no clues about what it is refusing now.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example that demonstrates the issue. E.g. remove fields and setters from the Commune class until the problem stops occurring.

Comment: @jon-hanson it won't be easy. I'm doing a step-by-step debugging instead, and might have the beginning of a solution. I hope that in few days, I can provide an helpful answer to all of those who will face this problem with the Spark new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is now corrected with the `Spark 3.4.2` new release.

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts in the `private def deserializerFor(enc: AgnosticEncoder[_], path: Expression, walkedTypePath: WalkedTypePath)` in the stack trace.

It attempts to run that piece of code:

```scala
case JavaBeanEncoder(tag, fields) =>
  val setters = fields.map { f =>
    val newTypePath = walkedTypePath.recordField(
      f.enc.clsTag.runtimeClass.getName,
      f.name)
    val setter = expressionWithNullSafety(
      deserializerFor(
        f.enc,
        addToPath(path, f.name, f.enc.dataType, newTypePath),
        newTypePath),
      nullable = f.nullable,
      newTypePath)
    f.writeMethod.get -> setter
  }
[...]
```

Here, among its searches, it searches for `isCollectiviteOutremer` method, and finds:

```scala
EncoderField(isCollectiviteOutremer,PrimitiveBooleanEncoder,true,{},Some(isCollectiviteOutremer),None)
```

(or something like that, I solved it in a debug). What is important is that for setter it has: `None`.

Because the method it tries to encode is that one:

```java
public boolean isCollectiviteOutremer() {
   return this.codeCommune != null &&
      (this.codeCommune.startsWith("975") || this.codeCommune.startsWith("977") || this.codeCommune.startsWith("978") || this.codeCommune.startsWith("98"));
}
```

That is an utilitarian method, and doesn't need a setter.

In fact, that method doesn't need to be encoded into a field, but I don't know how to tell to `Encoders.bean(...)` to skip it. If an annotation exists, or something else.

Whatever, I was able to remove that encoding attempt by changing its return type from `boolean` to `Boolean`, and then I hadn't the problem anymore: the method `isCollectiviteOutremer` wasn't listed in `fields` anymore.

My answer to this question counts, however, more for a workaround than a good solution.

Comment: This even breaks Dataset from bean Encoder, 
exactly produced same error when data set being generated.
no way we can pass the writeMethod to a field from instantiation 
ex:
`spark.createDataSet(Seq(myCustomClassItems))(Encoders.bean(Class[MyCustomClass]).toDS`

Comment: Merci Marc. Vous me sauvez la vie. J'avais aussi une méthode utilitaire getXXX qui n'était pas un getter sur un attribut et ça faisait planter ce couillon de Spark 3.4.0. Grâce à votre post ci-dessus, j'ai compris que je n'avais qu'à renommer cette méthode afin qu'elle ne commence pas par "get" et ça a résolu le problème.

Comment: Hi @marc-le-bihan or anyone, I also faced the same issue and it is due to the get method, may I know if there is other workaround other than renaming the get method, maybe using annotation?

Comment: @weikangchia Currently, I don't know. I'm awaiting the `Spark 3.4.2` version expecting they will correct this issue, because I'm trying to create a minimal test case in order to create an issue, but this is very long to do.

Comment: I see, thanks. I guess I shall go with renaming my method first and share here if I find anything useful.

Comment: I've created an issue about it, and two others linked troubles on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-45311