# Encoders.bean attempts to check the validity of a return type considering its generic type and not its concrete class, with Spark 3.4.0

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

That's a strange problem I stumbled into, since I've switched to *Spark* `3.4.0`

I have a class that isn't simple to fill, with `Encoders.bean` in *Java*:

Without going too deep, the class I have to fill with data, has a base class with generic types in it:

```java
public class ComptesIndividuels<MR extends ComptesTotalOuBaseEtParHabitant, RS extends ComptesAvecRatioStructure, RV extends ComptesAvecReductionVotee, TV extends ComptesAvecTauxVote> implements Serializable {
[...]
   /** Année d'exercice */
   private Integer anneeExercice;
   
   /** Nom de la collectivité */
   private String nom;

   /** PRODUITS DE FONCTIONNEMENT = A */
   private MR produitsDeFonctionnement;

   /** Produits de fonctionnement CAF */
   private MR produitsDeFonctionnementCAF;
   
   /** PRODUITS DE FONCTIONNEMENT = A : CAF : Impôts Locaux */ 
   private RS produitsDeFonctionnementCAFImpotsLocaux;

   /** PRODUITS DE FONCTIONNEMENT = A : CAF : Autres impôts et taxes */
   private RS produitsDeFonctionnementCAFAutresImpotsEtTaxes;

   /** PRODUITS DE FONCTIONNEMENT = A : CAF : Dotation globale de fonctionnement */
   private RS produitsDeFonctionnementCAFDGF;
   
   /** CHARGES DE FONCTIONNEMENT = B */
   private MR chargesDeFonctionnement;

   /** Charges de fonctionnement CAF */
   private MR chargesDeFonctionnementCAF;

   /** CHARGES DE FONCTIONNEMENT = B : CAF : Charges de personnel */
   private RS chargesDeFonctionnementCAFChargesDePersonnel;

   /** CHARGES DE FONCTIONNEMENT = B : CAF : Achats et charges externes */
   private RS chargesDeFonctionnementCAFAchatsEtChargesExternes;

   /** CHARGES DE FONCTIONNEMENT = B : CAF : Charges financières */
   private RS chargesDeFonctionnementCAFChargesFinancieres;

   /** CHARGES DE FONCTIONNEMENT = B : CAF : Subventions versées */
   private RS chargesDeFonctionnementCAFSubventionsVersees;
[...]
```

They are needed because departments, cities, local authorities, regions have the overhaul same structure, but with some small variations.

So, the concrete class I am willing to fill, for example, is a city individual accounts, `ComptesIndividuelsCommune` extending `ComptesIndividuels`:

```java
/**
 * Comptes individuels d'une commune.
 * @author Marc Le Bihan
 */
public class ComptesIndividuelsCommune extends ComptesIndividuels<ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate, ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate, ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee, ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate> {
[...]
   /** Code de la région */
   private String codeRegion;
   
   /** Code du département */
   private String codeDepartement;

   /** CHARGES DE FONCTIONNEMENT = B : CAF : Contingents */
   private ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate chargesDeFonctionnementCAFContingents;

   /** RESSOURCES D'INVESTISSEMENT : Retour de biens affectés concédés ... */
   private ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate ressourcesInvestissementRetourDeBiensAffectesConcedes;

   /** EMPLOIS D'INVESTISSEMENT : Charges à répartir */
   private ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate emploisInvestissementChargesARepartir;

   /** EMPLOIS D'INVESTISSEMENT : Immobilisations affectées, concédées, ... */
   private ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate emploisInvestissementImmobilisationsAffecteesConcedees;

   /** AUTOFINANCEMENT : Excédent brut de fonctionnement */
   private ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate autoFinancementExcedentBrutDeFonctionnement;
[...]
```

Until `Spark 3.3.2` I was able to fill it from a row dataset with proper properties, with this function:

```java
/**
 * Convertir un Dataset Row en Dataset de comptes individuels de communes.
 * @param dsRow Dataset Row à convertir.
 * @return Dataset de comptes de communes.
 */
@Override
public Dataset<ComptesIndividuelsCommune> toDatasetComptesIndividuels(Dataset<Row> dsRow) {
   Objects.requireNonNull(dsRow, "Le dataset de comptes individuels de communes ne peut pas valoir null.");
      
   return dsRow.map((MapFunction<Row, ComptesIndividuelsCommune>)row -> {
      ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate chargesDeFonctionnementCAFContingents = rs("\t\tContingents\t\t\t", "chargesDeFonctionnementCAFContingents", true, row); 

      ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate ressourcesInvestissementRetourDeBiensAffectesConcedes = rs("\tRetour de biens affectés, concédés, ...\t", "ressourcesInvestissementRetourDeBiensAffectesConcedes", true, row);
         
      ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate emploisInvestissementChargesARepartir = rs("\tCharges à répartir\t\t\t", "emploisInvestissementChargesARepartir", true, row); 
      ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate emploisInvestissementImmobilisationsAffecteesConcedees = rs("\tImmobilisations affectées, concédées, ...", "emploisInvestissementImmobilisationsAffecteesConcedees", true, row);

      ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate operationsInvestissementBesoinOuCapaciteFinancementResiduelSectionInvestissement = mr("Besoin ou capacité de financement résiduel de la section d'investissement = D - C", "operationsInvestissementBesoinOuCapaciteFinancementResiduelSectionInvestissement", true, row);
      ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate operationsInvestissementSoldeDesOperationsPourCompteDeTiers = mr("+ Solde des opérations pour le compte de tiers", "operationsInvestissementSoldeDesOperationsPourCompteDeTiers", true, row);
      ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate operationsInvestissementBesoinOuCapaciteFinancementSectionInvestissement = mr("Besoin ou capacité de financement de la section d'investissement = E", "operationsInvestissementBesoinOuCapaciteFinancementSectionInvestissement", true, row);
      ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate operationsInvestissementResultatEnsemble = mr("Résultat d'ensemble = R - E", "operationsInvestissementResultatEnsemble", true, row);
         
      ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate autoFinancementExcedentBrutDeFonctionnement = rs("Excédent brut de fonctionnement\t\t\t", "autoFinancementExcedentBrutDeFonctionnement", true, row);
         
      ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate endettementFondsDeRoulement = mr("FONDS DE ROULEMENT", "endettementFondsDeRoulement", true, row);
         
      ComptesIndividuels<ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate, ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate, ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee, ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate> comptesIndividuels = super.alimenterCompteIndividuels(row, 
         row.getAs("populationCommune"), row.getAs("sirenCommune"), row.getAs("codeCommune"), row.getAs("nomCommune"), true);
         
      return new ComptesIndividuelsCommune(comptesIndividuels,
         row.getAs("codeRegion"), row.getAs("codeDepartement"),
         row.getAs("typeGroupementAppartenance"),
         row.getAs("libelleStrateCommune"),
         ressourcesInvestissementRetourDeBiensAffectesConcedes,
         chargesDeFonctionnementCAFContingents,
         emploisInvestissementChargesARepartir, emploisInvestissementImmobilisationsAffecteesConcedees,
         autoFinancementExcedentBrutDeFonctionnement,  
         endettementFondsDeRoulement,
         operationsInvestissementBesoinOuCapaciteFinancementResiduelSectionInvestissement, 
         operationsInvestissementSoldeDesOperationsPourCompteDeTiers, 
         operationsInvestissementBesoinOuCapaciteFinancementSectionInvestissement, 
         operationsInvestissementResultatEnsemble); 
   }, Encoders.bean(ComptesIndividuelsCommune.class));
}
```

But since *Spark* `3.4.0`, it fails with this stacktrace:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkUnsupportedOperationException: [ENCODER_NOT_FOUND] Not found an encoder of the type RS to Spark SQL internal representation. Consider to change the input type to one of supported at 'https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html'.

    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotFindEncoderForTypeError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1483)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.encoderFor(JavaTypeInference.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.$anonfun$encoderFor$1(JavaTypeInference.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.ArrayOps$.map$extension(ArrayOps.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.encoderFor(JavaTypeInference.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.encoderFor(JavaTypeInference.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.encoderFor(JavaTypeInference.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.javaBean(ExpressionEncoder.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.bean(Encoders.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.bean(Encoders.scala)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.individuel.communes.ComptesIndividuelsCommunesDataset.toDatasetComptesIndividuels(ComptesIndividuelsCommunesDataset.java:614)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.individuel.AbstractComptesIndividuelsDataset.toComptesIndividuels(AbstractComptesIndividuelsDataset.java:119)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.balance.communes.ComptesIndividuelsCommunesIT.datasetComptesIndividuelsCommunesEPCI(ComptesIndividuelsCommunesIT.java:158)
```

I've started a debug session. The problem happens in the encoding checking.

This function is called (visible in the stacktrace) by the *Scala* engine of *Spark*:

```scala
private def encoderFor(t: Type, seenTypeSet: Set[Class[_]]): AgnosticEncoder[_] = t match {

  case c: Class[_] if c == java.lang.Boolean.TYPE => PrimitiveBooleanEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == java.lang.Byte.TYPE => PrimitiveByteEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == java.lang.Short.TYPE => PrimitiveShortEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == java.lang.Integer.TYPE => PrimitiveIntEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == java.lang.Long.TYPE => PrimitiveLongEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == java.lang.Float.TYPE => PrimitiveFloatEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == java.lang.Double.TYPE => PrimitiveDoubleEncoder

  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.lang.Boolean] => BoxedBooleanEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.lang.Byte] => BoxedByteEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.lang.Short] => BoxedShortEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.lang.Integer] => BoxedIntEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.lang.Long] => BoxedLongEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.lang.Float] => BoxedFloatEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.lang.Double] => BoxedDoubleEncoder

  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.lang.String] => StringEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[Array[Byte]] => BinaryEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.math.BigDecimal] => DEFAULT_JAVA_DECIMAL_ENCODER
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.math.BigInteger] => JavaBigIntEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.time.LocalDate] => STRICT_LOCAL_DATE_ENCODER
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.sql.Date] => STRICT_DATE_ENCODER
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.time.Instant] => STRICT_INSTANT_ENCODER
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.sql.Timestamp] => STRICT_TIMESTAMP_ENCODER
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.time.LocalDateTime] => LocalDateTimeEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.time.Duration] => DayTimeIntervalEncoder
  case c: Class[_] if c == classOf[java.time.Period] => YearMonthIntervalEncoder

  case c: Class[_] if c.isEnum => JavaEnumEncoder(ClassTag(c))

  case c: Class[_] if c.isAnnotationPresent(classOf[SQLUserDefinedType]) =>
    val udt = c.getAnnotation(classOf[SQLUserDefinedType]).udt()
      .getConstructor().newInstance().asInstanceOf[UserDefinedType[Any]]
    val udtClass = udt.userClass.getAnnotation(classOf[SQLUserDefinedType]).udt()
    UDTEncoder(udt, udtClass)

  case c: Class[_] if UDTRegistration.exists(c.getName) =>
    val udt = UDTRegistration.getUDTFor(c.getName).get.getConstructor().
      newInstance().asInstanceOf[UserDefinedType[Any]]
    UDTEncoder(udt, udt.getClass)

  case c: Class[_] if c.isArray =>
    val elementEncoder = encoderFor(c.getComponentType, seenTypeSet)
    ArrayEncoder(elementEncoder, elementEncoder.nullable)

  case ImplementsList(c, Array(elementCls)) =>
    val element = encoderFor(elementCls, seenTypeSet)
    IterableEncoder(ClassTag(c), element, element.nullable, lenientSerialization = false)

  case ImplementsMap(c, Array(keyCls, valueCls)) =>
    val keyEncoder = encoderFor(keyCls, seenTypeSet)
    val valueEncoder = encoderFor(valueCls, seenTypeSet)
    MapEncoder(ClassTag(c), keyEncoder, valueEncoder, valueEncoder.nullable)

  case c: Class[_] =>
    if (seenTypeSet.contains(c)) {
      throw QueryExecutionErrors.cannotHaveCircularReferencesInBeanClassError(c)
    }

    // TODO: we should only collect properties that have getter and setter. However, some tests
    //   pass in scala case class as java bean class which doesn't have getter and setter.
    val properties = getJavaBeanReadableProperties(c)
    // Note that the fields are ordered by name.
    val fields = properties.map { property =>
      val readMethod = property.getReadMethod
      val encoder = encoderFor(readMethod.getGenericReturnType, seenTypeSet + c)
      // The existence of `javax.annotation.Nonnull`, means this field is not nullable.
      val hasNonNull = readMethod.isAnnotationPresent(classOf[Nonnull])
      EncoderField(
        property.getName,
        encoder,
        encoder.nullable && !hasNonNull,
        Metadata.empty,
        Option(readMethod.getName),
        Option(property.getWriteMethod).map(_.getName))
    }
    JavaBeanEncoder(ClassTag(c), fields)

  case _ =>
    throw QueryExecutionErrors.cannotFindEncoderForTypeError(t.toString, SPARK_DOC_ROOT)
}
```

where it fails, on the line
`val encoder = encoderFor(readMethod.getGenericReturnType, seenTypeSet + c)`
it has called with that content below:

[image]

and then it jumps to the default case:

```scala
case _ =>
  throw QueryExecutionErrors.cannotFindEncoderForTypeError(t.toString, SPARK_DOC_ROOT)
```

throwing an exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkUnsupportedOperationException: [ENCODER_NOT_FOUND] Not found an encoder of the type RS to Spark SQL internal representation. Consider to change the input type to one of supported at 'https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html'.
```

and then I understand that the `t: Type` `encoderFor` is using, has for value `RS`...
and it appears me strange that such a type could hold a generic type declaration, instead of a concrete class, at this step.

I am clueless, here. I wonder what I could do to solve my problem.
Maybe I am in front of a Spark `3.4.0` issue?

---

For @DmytroMitin question about the differences between Spark `3.4.0` and Spark `3.3.2`, in his comment below: the Spark `3.3.2` is different.
Its method is called `inferDataType` and execute this piece of code:

```scala
case other =>
   if (seenTypeSet.contains(other)) {
      throw QueryExecutionErrors.cannotHaveCircularReferencesInBeanClassError(other)
     }

   // TODO: we should only collect properties that have getter and setter. However, some tests
   // pass in scala case class as java bean class which doesn't have getter and setter.
   val properties = getJavaBeanReadableProperties(other)
   val fields = properties.map { property =>
   val returnType = typeToken.method(property.getReadMethod).getReturnType
   val (dataType, nullable) = inferDataType(returnType, seenTypeSet + other)
   // The existence of `javax.annotation.Nonnull`, means this field is not nullable.
   val hasNonNull = property.getReadMethod.isAnnotationPresent(classOf[Nonnull])
    new StructField(property.getName, dataType, nullable && !hasNonNull)
  }
  (new StructType(fields), true)
}
```

and doesn't encouter the same problem:

```
returnType = fr.ecoemploi.metier.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate
```

it is able to define a StructType from that class:

[image]

I think code between `3.3.2` and  `3.4.0` have largely enough changed, and are incomparable now (for normal understanding).

Comment: Your code is not self-contained. What are the imports around `toDatasetComptesIndividuels`? What are `rs`, `mr`, `alimenterCompteIndividuels`? Please try to minimize your reproduction. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In 3.4.0 pattern matching falls to the default case. What codec (what case) was selected in 3.3.2? The codec for Java bean?

Comment: What is the difference with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76036349/encoders-bean-doesnt-work-anymore-on-a-java-pojo-with-spark-3-4-0 ?

Comment: @DmytroMitin this one affects the encoding, the other one the decoding. The two links do not describe the same error (not the same message, not the same behavior). A minimal example cannot be created in some contexts like such a complex Spark application, your remarks cannot apply here. Debug session description is provided instead.

Comment: The screenshot from debugger is not so useful without similar screenshot from 3.3.2 where everything was working. You could focus on differences.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I replied to your question in my question (added a section about it). Spark `3.3.2` and `3.4.0` have a largely different code for `Encoders.bean`, and they are now difficult to compare. Understanding their changes would be difficult.